# SQL query to get the bookmakers with the highest odds

Tags: sql, mysql

I try to solve an sql problem but without success and I thought that you could give me a good answer.

My table looks like this:

```
league_id|style|bookmaker|hometeam|awayteam|odd1|oddX|odd2|
-----------------------------------------------------------
premier  |1X2  |bet365   |arsenal |chelsea |2.50|3.20|2.30|
-----------------------------------------------------------
premier  |1X2  |unibet   |arsenal |chelsea |2.40|3.00|2.00|
-----------------------------------------------------------
premier  |1X2  |ladbrokes|arsenal |chelsea |2.60|3.20|2.10|
-----------------------------------------------------------
premier  |1X2  |bet24    |arsenal |chelsea |2.30|3.40|2.10|
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

odd1 = home team to win, odd2 = away team to win, oddX = draw

DESIRABLE OUTPUT:

```
Premier League Odds:

team    |AVERAGE|BEST|BEST ODDS BOOKMAKER|
-----------------------------------------
arsenal | 2.45  |2.60| ladbrokes          |
-----------------------------------------     
chelsea | 3.20  |3.40| bet24              |
-----------------------------------------     
Draw    | 2.12  |2.30| bet365             |
-----------------------------------------
```

you can see a live example here: http://www.wsn.com/football/football-odds/

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Could you add some, er, domain knowledge, ie how odds for wins of each team and a draw are calculated from the "odd1/2/X" values, please? Not everyone has ever visited a bet shop.

Comment: odd1 = home team to win, 
odd2 = away team to win, 
oddX = draw

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your dialect of SQL, using a subquery along these lines might be what you're looking for, in case I understand correctly what the numbers mean:

```
SELECT 
    tt.hometeam as team, 
    avg(tt.odd1) as average,
    max(tt.odd1) as best, 
    tt.bookmaker as best_odds_bookmaker
FROM
    2_team_table tt
INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            bookmaker as maxbookie
        FROM
            2_team_table 
        ORDER BY
            odd1 desc
        LIMIT 1
    ) as a
    ON tt.bookmaker = a.maxbookie
UNION ALL
   ..... ( same thing with awayteam and odd2 )
UNION ALL
   ..... ( same thing setting the first col to "Draw" and using oddX )
```

**BUT REALLY** you're much better off doing something like this in some scripting language, and it'll ONLY work like this if your table only contains two teams, one event, which is very unrealistic.